# ffmpeg Images to videos

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to input multiple images in ffmpeg when the images are not sequential?

Something like `-i image1.jpg otherimage.jpg newimage.jpg`?

I know how to use `-i img-%3d.jpg`, but this doesn't suit my needs.

---

The result of the answer from occvtech is 1 image

```
C:\ffmpeg>ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i image-001.png -i image-002.png -i image-003.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out234.mp4
ffmpeg version N-72259-g0b9d636 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 39.101 / 56. 39.101
  libavformat    56. 33.101 / 56. 33.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'image-001.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 600x600, 0.20 tbr, 0.20 tbn, 0.20 tbc
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'image-002.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, pal8(pc), 600x600, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, png_pipe, from 'image-003.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 600x600 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr,
25 tbn, 25 tbc
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] 264 - core 146 r2538 121396c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out234.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.33.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 600x60
0, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.39.101 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  150 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=      39kB time=00:00:03.26 bitrate=  99.0kbits/
frame=  150 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      44kB time=00:00:04.93 bitrate=  72.6kbits
/s dup=149 drop=0
video:41kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ov
erhead: 6.258604%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] frame I:1     Avg QP:15.55  size: 35176
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] frame P:38    Avg QP:16.05  size:    81
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] frame B:111   Avg QP:13.67  size:    29
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  0.0%  0.0% 98.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] mb I  I16..4: 49.5% 15.0% 35.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  1.0%  0.0
%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.3%  0.0
%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:40.4% L1:59.6% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] 8x8 transform intra:15.0% inter:41.4%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 41.8% 51.5% 44.6% inter: 0
.0% 0.2% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] i16 v,h,dc,p: 86%  3%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 19%  5%  5%  9%
12%  9% 10%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 18% 15%  7%  8%
 7%  7%  7%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] i8c dc,h,v,p: 65% 13% 13%  8%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] ref P L0: 97.6%  1.2%  0.7%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] ref B L0: 41.8% 58.2%
[libx264 @ 0000000002efda20] kb/s:66.31

C:\ffmpeg>ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally always find it easier to rename the files within my directory so that they are sequential (on windows - highlight all files, and hit F2 to rename).

However, if for some reason you want to input three jpg files manually (named image1.jpg, otherimage.jpg, and newimage.jpg), you can do it by individually using the `-i` flag.

`ffmpeg -i image1.jpg -i otherimage.jpg -i newimage.jpg ....`

Comment: I have try like this but there will be just one image on video. Can you please show me an example ?

Comment: Please describe what your end goal is.  Also it will help if you include your console output.

Comment: If i use it like this the result will be a video with 1 image. ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i image-001.png -i image-002.png -i image-003.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out234.mp4

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the images so that they playback like a video sequence?

Easiest way will be to `-i image-%03d.png`.

If for some reason you don't want to do that like it says in your OP, you can use concatenate: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate. 

There are 3 primary kinds of concatenating in FFmpeg.  I'm partial to the concatenate filter.  You would need to use the following command:
`ffmpeg -i image-001.png -i image-002.png -i image-003.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[out]" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out234.mp4`